# json object split into two json objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON Object

```
{1: "test projekt", 4: "Second Project", 
 5: "Third Project", 6: "Fourth Project", 
 7: "5th one", 8: "6th one dude", 
 uhash: "7021a11332508b6e30d3b6d3e95180398228b0e4010fc3f05db81e80"}
```

i want to split it into:

```
{1: "test projekt", 4: "Second Project", 
 5: "Third Project", 6: "Fourth Project", 
 7: "5th one", 8: "6th one dude"}
```

and

```
{uhash: "7021a11332508b6e30d3b6d3e95180398228b0e4010fc3f05db81e80"}
```

how can I do it in js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to manipulate JSON is to parse it into objects, manipulate the objects and then create JSON from the objects:

```
var o = JSON.parse(json);

var o2 = { uhash: o.uhash };
delete o.uhash;

var json1 = JSON.stringify(o);
var json2 = JSON.stringify(o2);
```

Note: The [JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227901/json-object-split-into-two-json-objects/25228005#25228005) is not supported in older browers, e.g. IE 7.

Comment: thank you for showing the complete way, i didnot use stringify, now i do. nice!

Answer (score 2):

something like this ?

```
var secondObj = {uhash: firstObj.uhash};
delete firstObj.uhash;
```

for something more complex you can use underscore : [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/). take a look at groupBy or map. depends on what exactly do you need.

Answer (score 1):

The `for ... in` loop will iterate over object keys. Be sure to limit it using the `hasOwnProperty` method otherwise `for ... in` will find all inherited keys of the object. Once you can iterate over the object, all you need to do is check the keys and populate two other objects.

```
var numbers = {},
    uhash   = {},
    prop    = '';

for (prop in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

        if (!isNaN(prop)) {
            numbers[prop] = json[prop];
        } else {
            uhash[prop] = json[prop];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
function popAttributeFromData (attrs, data) {
  for (var key in data) {
    if(key === attrs) {
      var result = {
        attrs: data[attrs]
      };
      delete data[attrs];
      return result;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

What it does it iterating through the `keys` from data until the key matches with the passed parameter `attrs`.

Here is the result
[image]

[PLAYGROUND](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/zxatr)